# How to keep options state after losing focus on async-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Using the  component of 'react-select' I have troubles with the options state. After the 'blur' event the options are set to the default ones, however the `inputValue` is still set. How to avoid such an options reset?

"react" 16.8.6
"react-select" 2.4.2

I provide all the props to the components according to the docs https://react-select.com/props#async-props, including `loadOptions` returning Promise, that resolves with options list, `defaultOptions` as true, `cacheOptions` as true, `inputValue` from my component's state, `onInputChange` changing the state's `inputValue` on the actions except 'input-blur' and 'menu-close'.

```js
onInputChange = (inputValue, { action }) => {
  if (!['input-blur', 'menu-close'].includes(action)) {
    this.setState({ inputValue });
  }
};
```

```js
loadOptions = input => {
  return getOptions(input);
};
```

```js
<Async
  cacheOptions,
  defaultOptions,
  onInputChange={onInputChange}
  loadOptions={loadOptions}
  inputValue={inputValue}
>
```

I expect the options after 'focus' to be kept same as before 'blur', but options are set to default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs provided for props of `<Async> onChangeInput` are not totally correct.

```
function (
  string,
  {
    action required One of <
      "set-value",
      "input-change",
      "input-blur",
      "menu-close"
    >
  }
) => undefined
```

It's not always `undefined` expected to be returned from the function.

When handling the change `<Async>` gets the `inputValue` returned from `onInputChange`. Returning `inputValue` from my state solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution i've just found is to store in a state the response to return on loadOptions, and pass it as a prop as "defaultOptions". Following your code:

```
const [defaultOptions, setDefaultOptions] = useState();
```

```
loadOptions = input => {
  const res = getOptions(input);
  setDefaultOptions(res);
  return res;
};
```

And:

```
<Async
  cacheOptions
  defaultOptions={defaultOptions}
  onInputChange={onInputChange}
  loadOptions={loadOptions}
  inputValue={inputValue}
>
```